# Is this :$\int_{-1}^{1}\exp (-\tanh^{-1} (x))dx=\pi$ a well known integral representation for $\pi $?

Tags: integration, pi, transcendental-numbers

I have tried to get interesting integral for interesting transcendental number , I have got the following :$\int_{-1}^{1}\exp (-\tanh^{-1} (x))dx=\pi$ , really I didn't accross [that integral](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral(+exp(+-(arctanh(x))),+x%3D-1+to+1) in the web as shown [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/Constants/Pi/07/01/), Now I ask if the titled integral is a  well known integral representation or no , And how i can evaluate that ?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: 
$${{\tanh }^{-1}}\left( x \right)=\frac{1}{2}\ln \frac{1+x}{1-x}$$
[check this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1239885/proving-int-01-sqrt-frac1-x1xdx-frac%CF%802-1)

Comment: you are right, probably it is a simplification for well known integral representations of pi

Comment: indded see the link in the answer

Comment: Ok, I don't know if that was montioned in 16 formula representation of pi i linked above in question